# Remove "mouseleave" event on some behaviour

Tags: jquery, html

I have a DIV with `mouseleave` event triggered so any time I leave the DIV it is hide. This DIV contains a form with `input#login_user`. I'm checking in a function for some values, see below:

```
$(".cart").click(function() {
    checkLogin(function(data){
        if (data.status) {
            // Some code here
        } else {
            alert("You must login"); // Change
            $(".top-bar li, .top-bar li.has-dropdown").trigger("mouseenter");
            $("#login_user").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

So as you may see if `data.status` is false the event `mouseenter` is triggered and `input#login_user` should take focus. How I prevent the mouseleave event after trigger the mouseenter? Also focus never happen, why?

**UPDATE**

[This](http://pastie.org/8257719) is the code where the element that have the `mouseleave` event resides (see lines 116 ~ 132). And this is the code for `checkLogin`:

```
function checkLogin(callback) {
  $.post(Routing.generate('_loginStatus'), null, function(responseData) {
    if (callback != undefined)
      callback(responseData);
    else
      handleLoginResponse(responseData);
  });
}
```

Comment: use a global variable...to prevent `mouse leave`...after `mouse enter`,  secondly does the element `#login_user` exist when you call focus? you can't focus a hidden element.

Comment: You should probably post the `checkLogin` function so we can see the callback and what it returns? Is it async?

Comment: @adeneo I've updated the main post, take a look now